# Омонимичность при переводе

Tags: омонимы, переводы

Друзья, подскажите. Как в лингвистике называется ситуация, когда два разных по смыслу иностранных слова одинаково переводятся на русский язык? К примеру, с английского языка слова "house" и "home" имеют в русском только один аналог "дом". Хотя в первом случае речь идет о доме, как здании, а во втором - как жилище.

Comment: Пример не самый удачный из-за разницы значений и употреблении. "home" это точно соотвуетвует "домой", а значение "дом=жилище" в русском переводе выглядит не совсем по-русски, если не сказано чей это дом.   Возьмите, лучше *масло*: *butter* и *oil*. Тут без вопросов.

Comment: А вот специального термина, боюсь, нет. Это не лингвистика как таковая, интерес может быть только у переводчиков. Ну, поскольку им-то интересна ситуация обратная, перевод **многозначного слова**, то вряд ли для вашего "прямого" перевода есть общеупотребительный термин. Ну назовите *омонимией  (омографией) при переводе* или *переводной омонимией* - поймут наверняка.

Comment: В продолжении предыдущего вопроса... В английском языке есть два термина, которые на русский переводятся как юрист - это "lawyer" и "jurist". Так, если первый означает - лицо, занимающееся юридической практикой, то второй - человек, изучающий право. Иными словами, юрист-практик и юрист-теоретик. Можно ли здесь говорить омонимии или же тут будет полисемия?

Comment: С точки зрения английского,  это слова и разные значения. Поэтому в русском при переводе возникает полисемия. Но это с точки зрения английского. Для носителя русского тут даже омонимии-то не просматривается. Надо ж еще и культуру учитывать, менталитет. Чем юрист лучше физика, который тоже может быть теоретиком и экспериментатором, но на этом основании никто ж не будет говорить о многозначности слова "физик"?!

Comment: А с чем вообще ваш интерес связан? Практических-то проблем при переводе с английского на русский тут не должно возникать. Вот обратно - это да. Но в любом случае вам лучше на к переводчикам, на специализированные ресурсы.

Comment: Согласен с @behemothus: вчера специально искал, нет термина для этого явления. Просто перевод разных значений в языке-источнике разными словами языка-цели.

Comment: @Evgenie-red, в русском языке есть слово **правовед**, которым как раз можно обозначить человека, изучающего право.

Comment: @behemothus вопрос был о том как называется подобный феномен, а не о том как переводить. Этот феномен в лингвистике  называется полисемией, а семантика и проблемы перевода -это и есть разделы лингвистки. В общем случае лингвистика является теоретизированной наукой , не привязанной к конкретному языку

Comment: @Swift Допустим, хотя и с трудом. Но почему вы именно мне рассказываете свои соображения о месте лингвистики? Я задал один-единственный вопрос о том, с чем связан интерес к данной проблеме. Вы на него не ответили. Чем косвенно и подтвердили, что  вопрос совершенно надуманный. При всей теоретизированности (якобы) лингвистики, изобретать названия для явлений умозрительных, ничем не примечательных... Если бы вы объяснили причину интереса (автора или вашего), может бы и название вспомнилось...

Comment: @behemothus Так вы то название первым вспомнили! Полисемия не есть признак одного языка как изолированного множества классов. это признак лингвистической единицы,  наблюдаемый при сравнении одного языка с другим в поисках аналогий,  и именно лингвистика позволяет  правильно переводить с одного языка на другой, с учетом, конечно же, контекста и культурного простанства (пространства мемов)

Comment: @behemothus Возможна другая ситация, например слово мир имеет два  несвязанных значения (переводимых на тот же английский  как world  и peace). Так вот, это не одно слова, а ДВА. Разных по происхождению и значения их не связаны, просто в современном написании пишутся одинаково (раньше были разные буквы вместо и). В таком случае это омонимы. В других языках такое встречается  по  тем же причинам - смена  правописания и алфавита, это и есть так называемые "исторические причины". Другой такой причиной может быть множественное заимствование из схожих языков

Comment: @Swift Почитайте внимательно, как и для чего я вспомнил термин.

Comment: @Swift *Возможна другая ситация,* возможна. Но автору вопроса она не интересна.

Answer (score 0):

Этим вопросом занимается семантика. Существует понятие семы, минимальной неделимой единицы значеня. Большинсто реальных слов могут соответствовать целому набору сем,  если все значения связаны между собой. Синонимы могут пересекаться не полностью по этому набору. Home и house, строго говоря, не являются синонимами, просто дом в русском языке обладает семами обоих слов в анлийском.House - это постройка, здание, дом. Home (происходяшее от германского heim) - это место обитания, родина, обитель, жилье, дом как место обитания. Таким образом, слово "дом" является *полисемой*, имея два значения, связанные только в одном случае - если речь идет об одном и том же месте.

Полисеми́я (от греч. πολυσημεία — «многозначность») — многозначность, многовариантность, то есть наличие у слова (единицы языка, термина) двух и более значений, исторически обусловленных или взаимосвязанных по смыслу и происхождению.

В современном языкознании выделяют грамматическую и лексическую полисемии. Так, форма 2 лица ед. ч. русских глаголов может быть употреблена не только в собственно-личном, но и в обобщённо-личном значении. Ср.: «Ну, ты всех перекричишь!» и «Тебя не перекричишь». В подобном случае следует говорить о грамматической полисемии.

Часто, когда говорят о полисемии, имеют в виду прежде всего многозначность слов как единиц лексики. Лексическая полисемия — это способность одного слова служить для обозначения разных предметов и явлений действительности, ассоциативно связанных между собой и образующих сложное семантическое единство. Именно наличие общего семантического признака отличает полисемию от омонимии и омофонии: так, например, числительное «три» и «три» — одна из форм повелительного наклонения глагола «тереть», семантически не связаны и являются омоформами (грамматическими омонимами).

Comment: Вы вопрос-то поняли? Автору интересна конкретная ситуация межъязыкового соответвия одного слова языка-источника разным словам языка-мишени. Вы о том, даже не вспоминаете.

Comment: behemothus Это и есть полисемия при переводе. Сам факт такого соответствия и привел к возникновению понятия семы в лингвистике, точно также как   феномены изучаемые культороведением  привели к возникновению понятия мема. Кроме изучения самой дисциплины стоит уделить внимание и истории ее развития

Comment: Вижу, что вопроса не поняли. Полисемия при переводе возникает, когда одному слову языка-источника соответствуют разные в языке мишени.  И весь ваш ответ на эту тему. А вопрос - об обратной ситуации. ***Разным словам в источнике соответствует одно слово в языке цели***. Здесь и проблемы-то нету. Не то что термина для её обозначения.

Comment: @behemothus от перемены мест субъектов смысл предиката не меняется. Оригинал вообще не пользуется этой вашей целью-мишенью-источником как терминологией.  Два значения соответствую одному слову, одно слово соответствует двум значениям - это одно то же. Вместо английских слов  можно было воспользоваться двумя русскими: здание и жилье. С точки зрения лингвистики это НИЧЕГО не меняет.

Comment: Я другого мнения. Меняется. Уже потому, что практическая надобность в таком понятии отпадает, проблем перевода не возникает. Все ваши рассуждения на тему "одно и то же" умозрительны. + "Оригинал" не пользуется терминологией, но у него недвусмысленно это сказано. И в обсуждении никто не поставил так вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Как правило, полисемия сулит переводчику трудности, но иной раз может и пособить. Скажем, именно она выручает при переводе известного стихотворения Мандельштама:

Сохрани мою речь навсегда за привкус несчастья и дыма,
  За смолу кругового терпенья, за совестный дёготь труда.

У слов "смола" и "дёготь" есть в английском эквиваленты: "pitch" и "tar". Но, как водится, сохраняя значение, они не несут в себе всю сумму возможных коннотаций. В этом смысле, ситуация со второй строкой почти безнадёжна.

К счастью, английское "pitch" имеет два значения: "тембр голоса" и "смола".  Потому англоязычный читатель не удивится, встретив употреблениа этого слова  применительно к речи. Поначалу он воспримет "pitch" в первом его значении, "тембр". Ho за этим произойдёт переход ко второму значению, которое и имел в виду Мандельштам ("смола"), если сразу за "pitch" поставить "tar":

May you keep and remember forever my speech for its taste of misfortune and smoke,
  For its pitch and its tar, for my long humble patience and labour to death.

Answer (score -1):

Поскольку речь идет именно о переводе, то в вашем случае, скорее, корректнее было бы говорить не о термине в обшей лингвистке, а о переводческом термине, который применяется при переводе таких единиц.

Поскольку наш форум посвящен русскому языку, а не переводу, не вдаваясь в подробности, скажу, что этот способ перевода называется сужением или конкретизацией.

Comment: Ну при чем тут сужение? Вы вопрос-то поняли? Он не о способе перевода вообще.